# how to change opacity of image kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How do I change the transparency of the images to 50%?

```
class MyBackground(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        x = randint(1,10)
        print (x)
        y = 'water.png'
        if x==1:
            y = 'a.png'
        if x==2:
            y = 'b.png'
        if x==3:
            y = 'c.png'
        if x==4:
            y = 'd.png'
        if x==5:
            y = 'e.png'
        if x==6:
            y = 'f.png'
        if x==7:
            y = 'g.png'
        if x==8:
            y = 'h.png'
        if x==9:
            y = 'i.png'
        if x==10:
            y = 'j.png'
        super(MyBackground, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.bg = Rectangle(source=y, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        self.bind(pos=self.update_bg)
        self.bind(size=self.update_bg)
```

how do I do this without changing the rgb value? if I try it just ends up white.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary in place of all of those `if` statements?
    
    `pic_dic = {1: 'a.png', 2: 'b.png, ...}`

Then call your `if` and refer to your dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
with self.canvas:
  self.opacity = 0.5
  self.bg = Rectangle(source=y, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
  self.bind(pos=self.update_bg)
  self.bind(size=self.update_bg)
```

Reference: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html#kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas.opacity

Answer (score 1):

In your kivy file
make these modifications

```
Color:
            rgb: (1, 1, 1,a)
```

Check this link in [docs](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.color)

```
Image color, in the format (r, g, b, a).
```

Where `'a'` is alpha.

Setting the alpha part to the opacity level you want will give you image opacity.